# Rails 4: how to use string interpolation into Ruby regex in model helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, string-interpolation

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following post helper:

```
def link_highlight(string)
  init1 = string
  result1 = string.to_s.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
  if result1.nil?
    init1
  else
    result1
  end
end
```

I use it to style links in the `post.copy` `string`, thanks to the `highlight` class.

Now, I would like to pass a second `argument` to the method, so that I can apply different styles to the links, thanks to different `highlight` classes:

```
def link_highlight(string, color)
  init1 = string
  result1 = string.to_s.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight-color">\1</span>')
  if result1.nil?
    init1
  else
    result1
  end
end
```

When I do that, the class applied to the links in the string is actually `highlight-color`.

Instead, I would like to `link_highlight(string, blue)` to apply the `highlight-blue` class to the string.

—————

**UPDATE**: I tried the solution offered by @dankohn but it is actually not working.

If I do:

```
def link_highlight(string, color)
  init1 = string
  result1 = string.to_s.gsub!(/((https|http)?:\/\/[\S]+)/, '<span class="highlight-#{color}">\1</span>')
  if result1.nil?
    init1
  else
    result1
  end
end
```

Then I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `color' for #<#<Class:0x007f911de61698>:0x007f911995f518>
```

So, I also tried to run:

in my view, but then I get back to the initial problem and get:

```
#{"color"}">
```

displayed instead of the value of color.

—————

How can I replace `color` by its `value`? Can I use string interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `"<span class=\"highlight-#{color}\">\1</span>"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I thought but I must have tried it wrong the first time. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry, I had to unaccept your answer, because it does not seem to actually work, as you can see in the **UPDATE** section of my question. I am glad to accept it again once I can fix my issue ;) Thanks.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a block, it's easier to deal with:

```
string.gsub(/https?:\/\/\S+/){|link| "<span class=\"highlight-#{color}\">#{link}</span>"}
```